# How to check status of previously executed command in perl

Tags: oracle, perl, perlscript

I am completely new to Perl . I have a Perl script which check connection to a oracle database running in a container . Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

$\="\n";

print "Connecting to DB..";


my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=oracle;sid=ORCLCDB;port=1521', 'books_admin/MyPassword', '',{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 })or die print ("could not connect! $DBI::errstr \n");
```

Using this script I'm able to connect with  oracle database . But this script doesn't give any status  output to my terminal . How can i check the script is connected to database?. I know bash has $? for checking the status of previously executed cmd. Do we have something similar in Perl?

Here is what i want 
Output "Successfully connected to Oracle-db" when the connection is OK and failed status when script can't connect to database

Note:This code give  error status to my terminal. 
My Perl version is v5.16.3

Comment: If you put the command in an `eval` block, you can capture the output with `$@` -- see https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Comment: Peruse [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for a variety of goodies (`$?` among them). Otherwise, it depends on the library / function (etc) and how it behaves; so read docs to see what they do on failure and then work with that. Also, complex libraries (like `DBI`) often have specific methods to query status.

Comment: @richyen The `eval` block and `$@` are useful if code in the block throws an exception (`die`s), since we get the control back (the program isn't terminated); the exception gets "caught."  Without an exception raised there should be nothing in `$@` so it can't be used for general queries of status of previous commands (see it under [Error Variables in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)).  And many (most) libraries _don't_ throw (`die`) on error but (may) set `$?` (and perhaps other related globals, see `perlvar`) and may return codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for the `connect()` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect) says this:

> Establishes a database connection, or session, to the requested `$data_source`. Returns a database handle object if the connection succeeds. Use `$dbh->disconnect` to terminate the connection.
>
> If the connect fails (see below), it returns `undef` and sets both `$DBI::err` and `$DBI::errstr`. (It does not explicitly set `$!`.) You should generally test the return status of `connect` and print `$DBI::errstr` if it has failed.

So your code could be as obvious as:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
if ($dbh) {
  say 'Connection ok';
} else {
  die "Connection error: $DBI::errstr";
}
```

However, you're using `RaiseError => 1`, so your program will `die` rather than returning `undef`. So if your program gets past that line, you know the connection was successful.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
say 'Connection ok';
```